# FileDialog object, unfiltered file types selectable

Tags: vba, filedialog

The FileDialog shows only the file types given in the filter. That's right.

[image]

But if something is entered in the File Name field, then all file types will be displayed:

[image]

Now every file type can be selected AND opened.

Thats not good.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must filter (again) the `FileDialog` **result**...

```
If LCase(Right(.SelectedItems(1), 4)) = "xlsm" Then
        'do whatever you need
End If
```

Comment: @R L: I wouldn't say a bug, even if it can be so considered... It is the way of Windows doing such an operation, I would say. If you try to manually save something open in Notepad (VBScript, even .dll etc.) it tries saving it as .txt, but you can choose 'All files (*.*)' and save it like you need...